# is it meaningful to talk about size of eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am currently on a text and the author make mention "Therefore, the optimal vector is the smallest eigenvector of a matrix".

Note: all eigenvectors arising from this matrix has coefficients that sums to 1.

From my understanding of undergraduate linear algebra, it is only meaningful to talk about the size of eigenvalues and with the note above, I am confused.

Is the author trying to say "small eigenvector" as being an eigenvector whose corresponding eigenvalue is "small"?

Comment: Yes , precisely.

Comment: That statement is nonsense, without further clarification by the author. But perhaps the author means an eigenvector corresponding to the least eigenvalue of a matrix $A$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.